# Getting a 404 in Spring RESTful controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to do a restful service in spring mvc. This is my controller code,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/manageuser")
public class ManageUserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteuser/{user}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    protected void deleteUser(@PathVariable String user, ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println(user);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/adduser/{user}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    protected void addUser(@PathVariable String user, ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println(user);
    }

}
```

My manageuser-servelt.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.web" use-default-filters="false" 
>
<context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>


<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

My web.xml content,

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>manageuser</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:manageuser-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>manageuser</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/manageuser</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I am getting a 404 if I navigate to localhost/manageuser/adduser/Barney. What am I doing wrong here? Is this the right approach for RESTful services using spring-mvc?

Comment: Try localhost/manageuser/manageuser/adduser/Barney - you repeat manageuser in your web.xml and your controller

Comment: No, I am still getting 404

Comment: Are you definitely serving on port 80? Not say 8080 - eg localhost:8080/manageuser/manageuser/adduser/Barney I tried your code, but not your servlet mapping and it was fine. As a test change the url-pattern to /

Comment: What is the path of you servlet xml?

Comment: try changing the contextConfigLocation to `classpath:/manageuser-servlet.xml` and let me know if it works.

Comment: This is what I had in my web.xml, it worked for my other controller though! <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:manageuser-servlet.xml</param-value>

Answer (score 0):

Does "the System.out.println(user)" display the user ? If not, you have a problem in your mapping.

Check another Blog here : http://www.breathejava.com/restful-web-service-tutorial-spring-xml/.